# OPA & Istio - create basic example with different image?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, opa

This quick start is awesome - works great and gives a good example of using OPA and Istio: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/envoy-tutorial-istio/

If I use the same steps but instead copy the quick_start.yaml and just change the image and redeploy or do a clean deploy again, (for instance, replace the 2 instances of `openpolicyagent/opa:latest-istio` for image with `openpolicyagent/opa:0.53.1-istio-2-static`), I don't see that making a difference.  In fact, I don't even see the container on the pod.

With my example rest server, this is what I see:

```
kubectl get pod -o="custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,INIT-CONTAINERS:.spec.initContainers[*].name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name"
NAME                        INIT-CONTAINERS   CONTAINERS
rest-5b5b8db9dc-pj646       istio-init        rest,istio-proxy
```

Why is the `openpolicyagent/opa:latest-istio` not there and instead `istio-proxy` is listed, and how do I change it?